# Increase UIWebView storage (UIWebKitStorage)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Im using an HTML5 webform for iOS and Android. The safari has an storage limit of 50 MB of local webkit storage in the native iOS browser.
Im loading the webform URL now in a UIWebView and i want to increase this storage to its native app bundle. How can i do this?

Its not an AppStore app, so it can be a hack..

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any method to set the local storage limit. I will assume you use a JS API to store your content. Have you read the following documents ?

- [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH4-SW1)
- [Safari Client Side Storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1-DontLinkElementID_20)

Comment: I want to in my own UIWebView increase the size of Persistent Quota for a WebSQL.